# Will My Motherboard and CPU Support Newer RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, performance

So I'm looking at getting this (https://www.newegg.com/corsair-16gb-288-pin-ddr4-sdram/p/N82E16820236426?Item=N82E16820236426) RAM and I wanna know beforehand if it will be compatible with my CPU and Motherboard. I'm not super knowledgeable on this topic but I'm pretty sure the CPU and Mobo will downgrade the RAM to fit their max speed and then run it at its normal speed again once they support the RAM speed. I just want confirmation if I'm right. Thanks!

P.S: I don't really care about the speed of the RAM, mine's fine, I just want the extra GB's.

CPU: https://pcpartpicker.com/product/hV7CmG/intel-cpu-bx80662i36100

Mobo: https://pcpartpicker.com/product/6Q648d/msi-motherboard-b150mprovdh

Answer (score 0):

You were already most of the way there! PC Part Picker's compatibility check is great, so you just had to add the motherboard to your build then pick the RAM.

Temporary link is temporary: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/v4mTsZ

[image]